# Are question about official theme's bug on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, off-topic

From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions concerning third party plugins and themes are off-topic. However, would official themes and plugins be so?

- Yes, because they are still distinct to the WordPress source, and any themes and plugins should be equal?
- No, because they are official?

Below is my draft:

> I notice that in the Twenty Twenty-One theme, any paragraph that is outside the main content or contained in a container has no top and bottom margin. [A developer of the Stackable plugin says](https://github.com/gambitph/Stackable/issues/1068#issuecomment-784823357):
>
> > Upon checking, the gaps between native paragraphs are caused by these CSS rules:
> >
> > ```
> > .editor-styles-wrapper [data-block] {
> > margin-top: var(--global--spacing-vertical);
> > margin-bottom: var(--global--spacing-vertical); }
> > ```
> >
> > I believe this CSS is coming from Twenty Twenty-One theme.
> >
> > The `data-block` attribute is a unique identifier of added blocks inside the editor. Because of this, the margins are not visible in preview.
>
> I wonder if you can explain what these codes do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, themes and plugins managed by wordpress.org are on topic. They are "first party", meaning coming from WordPress directly, at least themes are even shipped with the core. Themes and plugin that are just *hosted* on wordpress.org but maintained by someone else are off-topic. So you can ask your question about any Twenty-X theme.

Comment: I think we can add this information in the help page?

Comment: Really, @fuxia, including generic HTML/CSS/JS/PHP stuff in those themes/plugins? 

Comment: if the plugins are made by Automattic, like Jetpack, would it be official?

Comment: @Ooker No, Automattic is a third party. See [Tom's answer](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4807/73) on a similar topic.